# Alert view is showing white rectangle in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7

The following code works perfectly from iOS 5 to 6.1. I even have applications in store with that code:

```
-(void)showActivityIndicator
{
    if(!mLoadingView) //
    {
        mLoadingView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        mLoadingView.tag = kAlertViewTag;
    }

    [mLoadingView show];
}

- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if (alertView.tag == kAlertViewTag)
    {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *actInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
        actInd.frame = CGRectMake(128.0f, 45.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f);
        [alertView addSubview:actInd];
        [actInd startAnimating];

        UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        l.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PRODUCT_PURCHASE_INDICATOR_TITLE", @"Please wait...");
        l.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];

        float strWidth = [l.text sizeWithFont:l.font].width;
        float frameWidth = alertView.frame.size.width;
        l.frame = CGRectMake((frameWidth - strWidth)/2, -25, 210, 100);

        l.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        l.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        l.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
        l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [alertView addSubview:l];
    }
}
```

It will show alert view without buttons and with activity indicator and label. However in iOS7 I can see only white rounded rectangle, no activity indicator.

What can I do to have this work from iOS 5 to 7?

Update:

To be more descriptive I'm adding screenshots. The following is iOS 5 to 6.1 screenshot. Works fine there.

[image]

The following is iOS7. As you can see even the size is smaller. Looks like it's not fully initialized or something.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

---

now `addSubview` is not available in `UIAlertView` in iOS7

The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified

As an alternative you can use [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD).

Comment: I don't think it's activity indicator problem. Please check my update. Thanks

Comment: This is true. Apple has intentionally blocked `addSubview` on alerts.

Comment: Do you have a link for that declaration?

Comment: @Keab42 see the [`UIAlertView Class Reference`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802) "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

Answer (score 20):

From iOS 7 onwards, you can do:

```
    [alertView setValue:customContentView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

to get custom content in a standard alert view.

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me. No need to implement those fancy custom stuff.

Comment: Only thing is that you have to call this before `[alertView show]`.

Comment: This sounds like something that is likely to not work in the future.

Comment: It is not a public API, but it is accepted for apps on the app store. You could say it is just as valid as using addSubView, that the OP mentions, which worked until iOS 7. However, as this was introduced by Apple in iOS7, I am guessing it is used by Apple's own apps when they show more than text in alerts.

Comment: Awesome answer! This worked much better than the solutions above (which also would work but this is so much easier).  This needs to be up-voted more.  Thanks!

Comment: You just can't replicate the system view and all of the parameters without a ton of code. This is a much cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 19):

I had to fix this problem very quickly, hence I have built an iOS7 UIAlertView-style UIView with its animations, which can be extended with any custom content.

There might be others who can use my solution, so I made [the whole code available on Github](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview).

[image]

Also, if you want to keep using the UIAlertView under previous OS versions, you have to fork the code. It might be as bad as it sounds, I'm using the following:

```
float sysVer = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (sysVer < 7) {
  // your old solution
} else {
  .. // iOS7 dialog code
}
```

(Please be aware that this is by no means a real solution - if Apple doesn't want us to use the dialogs for all sorts of things, then we probably shouldn't.)

Comment: can it be buttonless?

Comment: @RobCroll sure, i left the default xcode stuff by accident. feel free to use it as it is, ill update the files later asap.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. however this is still "buggy". if you try to add the CustomIOS7AlertView to a tableview, it still allows the user to scroll down the tableView. When using: CustomIOS7AlertView *alertView = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] initWithParentView:self.superview]; then the hierarchy is all messed up (i.e the tableview header appears above the alertView. Thanks for your help though... In my opinion stick with TSAlertView unti they decide to update to IOS7....

Comment: @GeorgeAsda make sure you pass on the right view in the initWithParentView:view method. If it's a tableview, the UIView will be attached there - perhaps you want to pass the view controller's view instead.

Comment: @Wimagguc i'm trying to pass this through uitableview cell

Comment: @GeorgeAsda: it makes sense then: its superview is still the table view only. DM me here or on twitter and i'll take a look at your code if you want.

Comment: @Wimagguc nothing fancy with my code. Setting up a custom cell with a button that displays an alertView.

- (IBAction)testButton {
    
    CustomIOS7AlertView *alertView = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] initWithParentView:self.superview];
    
    // Add some custom content to the alert view
    [alertView setContainerView:[self createDemoView]];

    
    [alertView show];
}
  - (UIView *)createDemoView
{
  //as per your example code nothing changes here
}

Comment: Another fork with another design here : https://github.com/kwent/ios-custom-alertview