# How to add multiple labels in UIAlert view in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7

I have custom alert view in iOS 6.0, which provide multiple labels and one button.In iOS 6.0 it is running properly, But in **iOS 7.0** custom alert view coming in **white alert view** and all label disappearing.

Any Solution?

Thanx.

Comment: Have a look at here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895106/alert-view-is-showing-white-rectangle-in-ios7/18895189#18895189

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it completely, but on `subclassing` a `UIAlertView`, you might be able to add `subviews`. The `[self addSubview:]` method can still be called from inside the `init` method of the `subclassed` `alertView`. I presume, it will be available in other parts of the code too.

You should try subclassing it.