# Adding UIActivityIndicatorView to UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to add an activity indicator inside the message , the uiAlert message, i tried basically everything on the internet, and nothing worked for me, i will just have the uialertview alone , here's my code

```
UIAlertView  *waitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait...." message:@"\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
progress.color = [UIColor blackColor];
[waitAlert addSubview: progress];
[progress startAnimating];
[waitAlert show];
```

This is what i end up having 
[image]

what am i missing!?

Comment: Why not use [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)… its a pretty neat library for loaders and very simple to use...

Comment: With `iOS7`, you can't add subview to `UIAlertView`. You'll have to do your own AlertView, or use one available on CocoaControls/GitHub.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alert view is showing white rectangle in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895106/alert-view-is-showing-white-rectangle-in-ios7)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7?lq=1

Comment: You can add subview on UIAlertView but subviews are not shown. You can check it's subview count property.

Comment: @Larme thank you, you were right, the best way to do so is to create my own alertView, if u please answer the question and i'll post it as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

in iOS 7 you cannot addSubview anything on UIAlertView,that was possible till iOS 6.1.so MBProgressHud is the best and simple solution for that

Comment: You can add subview on UIAlertView but subviews are not shown. You can check it's subview count property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your `UIActivityIndicator` using the `UIAlertViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *progress = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    progress.frame = CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30);

    [progress startAnimating];
    [alertView addSubview:progress];
}
```